Java Cipher.getInstance() failing on 'missing type' NoSuchPaddingException with try/catch
I have,
Cipher cipher = null;
try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    System.out.println("whut");
}

Eclipse wiggles on 'getInstance' and says
The method getInstance(String) from the type Cipher refers to the missing type NoSuchPaddingException

I'm confused by this.  Other answers on this site state that NoSuchPaddingException is a 'checked exception', falling under GenerateSecurityException.
Is this a configuration issue in Eclipse or something else?

This is a configuration issue. Eclipse has a section in its settings where you can configure which JDK to 'compile against', so to speak. It's called 'JREs' (you can use the filterbox to search for this). Whatever JRE you pointed eclipse at, it is incomplete or incompatible with eclipse (presumably, updating eclipse would address this). That or corrupt workspace config. To fix the latter, do a full rebuild (menu: Project... → Clean). Or simply close the project and open it again or restart eclipse, whatever you find easiest.

It was the settings.  I have JDK 22 installed, trying for JDK 17 compliance but somehow I ended up with something that disagreed.  Manually set everything to support 17, that cleared it.  You can provide an answer and I'll accept it, or if not, will type one up and include where I looked, what I reset, etc. -- thank you.

Sounds like you could do a better job at writing up the answer than I could. Feel free to copy as much of that comment as you need and I'll keep this page open for a bit so I can upvote once you've provided it :)

User @rzwitserloot pointed me in the right direction.
Steps to unblock the problem, from easiest to most involved, check after each step:

Clear the cache: Project -> Clean
Restart Eclipse
Select the project in the Package Explorer, then File -> Properties


Java Compiler
Deselect 'Enable project specific settings' if checked
Configure Workspace Settings... -> JDK Compliance -> Compiler compliance level:

At this point, pick.  Remember what you picked.  I have two JDKs installed, 17 and 22.  I picked 17 for this exercise.

Check the 'Use default compliance settings'

If you have a mismatch (ie, 'Compliance level' set to 19 but Generated .class files/Source compatibility you get a warning triangle: When selecting N compliance, make sure to have a compatible JRE installed and activated (currently Y). Configure...)
In my case, I had compliance level set to 19, generated class/source set to 17, and the JDK 22 activated.
At which point eclipse threw its hands in the air and walked out in a huff.

Once everything is in sync, Apply and Close.
You get a dialog, rebuild to apply? Yes.
Apply and Close

